# Check ordered subset in list

Tags: list-manipulation, subset, order

I need to find a function that checks if a list is contained in a larger list RESPECTING the order of the smaller one. For example `check[{a,b,c},{a,d,b,c}]` would return `True`, but `check[{a,b,c},{a,c,b,d}]` would return `False`. From what I see, the function `SubsetQ` doesn't seems to care about the order of the smaller list, but is there any function that does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `check = MatchQ[Riffle[#, ___, {1, -1, 2}]]@#2 &`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the elements of list1 are contained in list2, you may try:

-Select the elements of list 1 in list 2

-Check if the result is the same (elements AND order) as list 1:

We can define a function that will do this check:

```
check[l1_, l2_] := l1 === Select[l2, MemberQ[l1, #] &]
```

Now to test:

```
check[{a, b, c}, {a, c, b, d}]
(* False *)
check[{a, b, c}, {a, d, b, c}]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

> checks if a list is contained in a larger list RESPECTING the order of
> the smaller one

You could find the `Position` of each element of `{a,b,c}` in the other list. This will give you a list of numbers.

Now check if this list is always increasing.

To check if the list of numbers is always increasing, you can use `Differences` function on it, and look to see if it has no negative value or not. If not, then the order is respected i.e. `True` , else not i.e. `False`

Here is an example

```
L1 = {a, b, c};
L2 = {a, d, b, c};
p1 = Flatten[Position[L2, #] & /@ L1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Differences[p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since there are no negative values, then the sequence is increasing. Hence `True`

```
L3 = {a, c, b, d};
p2 = Flatten[Position[L3, #] & /@ L1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Differences[p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since there is negative value, then the sequence is not always increasing. Hence `False`

These can be easily made into a function if this meets what you want.

---

Here is the above in a function

```
check[lis1_List, lis2_List] := Module[{p},
  p = Flatten[Position[lis2, #] & /@ lis1];
  If[Select[Differences[p], # < 0 &] =!= {}, False, True]
  ]
```

And now

```
check[{a, b, c}, {a, d, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
check[{a, b, c}, {a, c, b, d}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ofcourse in Mathematica there is always at least 10 different ways to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

```
largerList = {a, d, b, c, d, a, b, d, c};
smallerList = {a, d, c};

Clear[patt, k]
patt[k_List] := 
 Flatten[Riffle[k, {Shortest[Except[#]] ...} & /@ Rest@k]]
```

---

For the first example the pattern can be found twice.

```
SequenceCases[largerList, patt[smallerList]]
```

> {{a, d, b, c}, {a, b, d, c}}

Also:

```
SequencePosition[largerList, patt[smallerList]]
```

> {{1, 4}, {6, 9}}

---

```
smallerList = {a, d, f};
SequenceCases[largerList, patt[smallerList]]
```

> {}

If you get an empty list, you can easily return `False` else `True` when you write your function using these techniques.